# Magento SOAP API get disabled categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, api, catalog, soap

I am working on a script (Python) which will need to get information of a category.
Simple as it seems, I thought. Well, I am bumping on the problem that I can't recieve the ID's of disabled categories.
My script gets the root catalog first. Getting "all_children", I will iterate over every child. Getting "all" the information I need.
Well, it seems that all_children does not have the ID's of disabled categories. 
This is an issue for me.
So my question is; **How do I get the ID's of disabled categories?**
I am using the `catalog_category.info` call. `catalog_category.tree` was kind of too confusing for me so I thought it would be better to just use `catalog_category.info` just for the sake of simplicity. Expecting to get all the information I needed from the `catalog_category.info`.
So is there a way to get it without using the `tree` call?
Any information, alternatives, guides or anything else will be appreciated.

P.S. Why would Magento API not return literally ALL children? Why does it skip the disabled ones?

Answer (score 1):

use the following code it has been tested and the output is giving category which are disabled also.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://yourmagentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('yourapiusername','yourapipassword');
$result = $client->catalogCategoryTree($session,2); // 2 is the id of default category (root category)
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hello Pradeep, thank you very much for answering. As I had stated in my question, I do not want to use the category tree. As it is kind of confusing to dynamically get categories. I might consider changing to tree though, if not possible otherwise. Thanks once again!